# I'm having troubles to compile a maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, maven

I've imported my project into Eclipse (Helios + m2eclipse), and also into Netbeans (7.0) and in both IDEs one of the troubles is:

This is what I get in Netbeans when I try to build.

The project com.miCompany:myProject:1.0 (.....) has 1 error

> Unresolveable build extension: Plugin
>   org.apache.axis2:axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin:1.3
>   or one of its dependencies could not
>   be resolved: Failed to collect
>   dependencies for
>   org.apache.axis2:axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin:jar:1.3
>   (): Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for
>   org.apache.woden:woden:jar:1.0-incubating-M7b:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.woden:woden:pom:1.0-incubating-M7b
>   from/to jibx
>   (http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven):
>   No connector available to access
>   repository jibx
>   (http://jibx.sourceforge.net/maven) of
>   type legacy using the available
>   factories
>   WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory ->
>   [Help 2]

This is what I get in Eclipse:

> Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin
>   org.apache.axis2:axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin:1.3
>   or one of its dependencies could not
>   be resolved: Failed to collect
>   dependencies for
>   org.apache.axis2:axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin:jar:1.3
>   ()    pom.xml /myProject  line 1  Maven
>   Problem

In Eclipse I've downloaded this: http://www.apache.org/dyn/mirrors/mirrors.cgi/axis/axis2/java/core/1.5.4/axis2-eclipse-service-plugin-1.5.4.zip unzipped and copied the file: "org.apache.axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin_1.5.4.jar" into the directory "plugins" of my Eclipse instalation. And I still getting the same error.

I am running Netbeans over Win XP and Eclipse over Win XP and also over Mac, allways the same error.

Does somebody have any idea what can I do?

Here goes my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>MyParent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>myModule</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>myModule</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>     
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>com/mycompany/client/*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin> 

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <packageName>com.mycompany.client</packageName>
                <wsdlFile>src/main/axis2/MyWsdl.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
                <targetResourcesFolderLocation>target/main/axis2</targetResourcesFolderLocation>
                <targetSourceFolderLocation>src/main/java</targetSourceFolderLocation>
                <namespaceURIs>
                    <namespaceURI>
                        <uri>http://schema.mycompany.com/Esb</uri>
                        <packageName>com.mycompany.services.Esbsrv.schema</packageName>
                    </namespaceURI>
                    <namespaceURI>
                        <uri>http://wsdl.mycompany.com/Esb</uri>
                        <packageName>com.mycompany.services.Esbsrv.schema</packageName>
                    </namespaceURI>
                    <namespaceURI>
                        <uri>http://schema.mycompany.com/Global/WSException</uri>
                        <packageName>com.mycompany.schema.global.wsexception</packageName>
                    </namespaceURI>
                </namespaceURIs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
  <!-- 
   <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
<!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
   -->
     </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you provide your pom.xml file please.

Comment: Are you able to build if you build the project directly from maven? Just go to your path where pom.xml is located, and execute `mvn clean package` and see what you get (mvn.bat or mvn.sh needs to be in PATH).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I can only offer suggestions as I"m not much of a maven expert, but I did just have to do this today and it was pretty straightforward for me -

- set up the maven project to be eclipse friendly : `mvn eclipse:eclipse`
- make sure eclipse can see the libs. this meant going to the projectsetup/buildpath/libraries editor in eclipse and adding the variable M2_REPO  to point to your local maven repository (e.g. something like /home/nacho3d/.m2/repository)

Your error, actually, looks to me like maven can't find a dependency for axis. The specifics for that should be on the axis website,

Comment: I had to put in my local repo a few libs developed by the people how developed the project that I was working.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're using maven 3.0+, right?

That pom(org.apache.woden:woden:jar:1.0-incubating-M7b) isn't compatible with maven 3 yet.
If you use maven 2.2.1 to build ESB 4.3.0-03 source, then it would be successfully.

Comment: I am using maven2. And I still can't get it running... Do you have any idea? Can it be that the version 1.3 is unavailable to keep using?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the jar of the missing dependency you can:

1) deploy it on your maven repository, if you have one

2) declare the dependency in your pom with a scope of 'system': [check this out](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem and fixed it by following below step...

1. In you project directory do the command: mvn eclipse:eclipse
2. In eclipse project right click->Maven->Update Project.
3. Again right click->Maven->Disable Maven Nature
4. Restart eclipse.
5. Right click on project->Configure->Convert to Maven Project.

Finish. Error will gone.

Thanks